# Wie weiß man, ob ein Fremdwort Maskulin, Feminin und Neutrum ist?

Tags: grammar, article

> Ein Blog, ein Gangbang, ein Gangster und so weiter.

Wie weiß man, ob ein Lehnwort Maskulin, Feminin und Neutrum ist?

Comment: I am not going to post this as an answer because I can't remember where I read this, but I seem to recall that loanwords in German are **typically** neuter (das).

Comment: Which is already disproved by above examples. Also consider *die Gang*, *die Party*, *der Spirit*, etc...

Comment: I read in "Der Dativ ist dem Genetiv sein Tod" that it's determined by the gender of the closest German word. Like for Nutella, "Produktnamen sind grundsätzlich sächlich," but it's "**die** Haselnusscreme." So the gender of the word isn't always clear but I assume eventually people will just pick a gender and it'll stick.

Comment: Das klappt nicht so einfach. Wenn ein Wort im Deutschen feminin ist, jedoch sagt das Fremdwort ganz anders.

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to know because most words don't answer to any kind of rule, however here are some tips to help you tackle those words: if the word ends in -heit -ung it is feminine.
If the word can resemble a verb, for example *essen*; it is Neutral. i.e. *das Essen* or *Das Entstehen*.

Comment: That's not related to the question.